# UPdating dataset

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio 2003 C# SQL Server 2000

I have a dataset on my form. I have added some fields to the database table
that this dataset uses, how do i update my dataset to show these extra fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rerun your select statement